# cannot compare message timestamp with x amount of days

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, momentjs

Hi I'm trying to delete messages that are 7 days old I'm using cron to schedule when this should happen. Here in my code I'm trying to fetch messages from a channel called `log_channel` then comparing the message timestamps to `const days = moment().add(7, 'd');` However I'm stuck at the if statement `if (msgs - days)` as this does not seem to return anything.

Here is my code for reference:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = new Event("ready", client => {
try{

    const log_channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "log")

    cron.schedule("0 18 22 * * *", function(){ 
        console.log("Attempting to purge log messages...");
        const days = moment().add(7, 'd');  // use moment the set how many days to compare timestamps with // 
        log_channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
            const msgs = Date.now(messages.createdTimestamp)
            if (msgs < days){
                log_channel.bulkDelete(100)
                console.log("messages deleted")
            }
            
        })
    })
```

Comment: Fetching multiple messages would return a collection of messages. `.createdTimestamp` exists on a *single* message object.

Comment: Does `.add(7, 'd')` add 7 days to the current date, making it a future date when what you are looking for is really 7 days in the past? If so, does `.add(-7, 'd')` give you the result you are after?

Comment: @Elitezen How would I get a single message object?

Comment: You can do `const arrayOfMessages = [...messages.values()]` and access or traverse individual messages

Comment: @Elitezen can you explain further with an example?

Comment: It will return an array. If you're unfamiliar with what an array is I highly recommend you first fully learn JavaScript before trying to use a Javascript library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I noticed your function wasn't an asynchronous function. We need to use a asynchronous function because we'll be using asynchronous, promise-based behavior your code.  `log_channel.messages.fetch` should be `await log_channel.messages.fetch` According to the Message#fetch() [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch) The fetch() method in this case simply returns asynchronous message object. Promise.

The next part is that you missed out `ForEach()`, forEach() executes the callbackFn function once for each array element.

Finally, you are also comparing the timestamp (a snowflake) with a moment object which will not work and the reason your `if` doesn't return true. If you want to get messages 7 days prior you can do something like this `moment.utc(msg.createdTimestamp).add( -7, 'd')` this will return all timestamps 7 days prior the last 100 messages. Note that Discord API limits you to 14 days so keep that in mind.

```
cron.schedule("* 18 22 * * *", async function(){
        console.log("Attempting to purge mod log messages...");
        await log_channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 })
        .then(messages => {
            messages.forEach(msg => {
                const timestamp = moment.utc(msg.createdTimestamp).add( -7, 'd');
                if (timestamp) {
                    log_channel.bulkDelete(5);
                } else {
                    return;
                }

            })
```